# Why did Java get uninstalled after I performed an Ubuntu update?

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, java

I was running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and it had a Java Running Environment (JRE) because I was using PyCharm, which requires that. I then authorized a system update and after rebooting Java is no longer available. PyCharm says `JAVA_HOME` is not defined (it used to be) and using `find . -name jre` from root does not reveal a JRE (I also tried `java` and `jdk`).

This strikes me as rather odd. What are possible reasons for this?

Running `dpkg -l | grep jre` gives me

```
ii  openjdk-14-jre-headless:amd64              14.0.1+7-1ubuntu1                   amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
```

which is the JDK I installed today after realizing I was missing Java.

Here's the log for the update day:

```
Start-Date: 2020-08-25  00:38:09
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libgs9:amd64 (9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.1, 9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.2), ghostscript:amd64 (9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.1, 9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.2), ghostscript-x:amd64 (9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.1, 9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.2), libgs9-common:amd64 (9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.1, 9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.2)
End-Date: 2020-08-25  00:38:13

Start-Date: 2020-08-25  00:38:15
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: bind9-host:amd64 (1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.2, 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3)
End-Date: 2020-08-25  00:38:17

Start-Date: 2020-08-25  00:38:33
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libsnmp-base:amd64 (5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.2, 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3)
End-Date: 2020-08-25  00:38:34

Start-Date: 2020-08-25  00:38:40
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libsane-common:amd64 (1.0.29-0ubuntu5, 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.1), libsane:amd64 (1.0.29-0ubuntu5, 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.1)
End-Date: 2020-08-25  00:38:45

Start-Date: 2020-08-25  00:38:58
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: sane-utils:amd64 (1.0.29-0ubuntu5, 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.1)
End-Date: 2020-08-25  00:39:01

Start-Date: 2020-08-25  00:39:15
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.1, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2), curl:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.1, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2)
End-Date: 2020-08-25  00:39:19

Start-Date: 2020-08-25  00:39:27
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: gnome-shell-common:amd64 (3.36.1-5ubuntu1, 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2), gnome-shell:amd64 (3.36.1-5ubuntu1, 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2)
End-Date: 2020-08-25  00:39:31

Start-Date: 2020-08-25  00:39:43
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libsnmp35:amd64 (5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.2, 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3)
End-Date: 2020-08-25  00:39:44

Start-Date: 2020-08-25  00:39:59
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: bind9-dnsutils:amd64 (1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.2, 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3), bind9-libs:amd64 (1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.2, 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3)
End-Date: 2020-08-25  00:40:04

Start-Date: 2020-08-25  00:40:19
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.1, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2)
End-Date: 2020-08-25  00:40:19

Start-Date: 2020-08-31  17:43:30
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (79.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 80.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-08-31  17:43:31

Start-Date: 2020-08-31  17:43:43
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libnss3:amd64 (2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.4, 2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.5)
End-Date: 2020-08-31  17:43:45

Start-Date: 2020-08-31  17:43:59
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox:amd64 (79.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 80.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-08-31  17:44:04

Start-Date: 2020-08-31  17:53:38
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.140'
Install: libllvm10:amd64 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1, automatic), python3-click:amd64 (7.0-3, automatic), python3-colorama:amd64 (0.4.3-1build1, automatic)
Upgrade: libreoffice-style-breeze:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), evince:amd64 (3.36.0-2, 3.36.7-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-math:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), evolution-data-server-common:amd64 (3.36.3-0ubuntu1.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu1), gnome-calendar:amd64 (3.36.1-1, 3.36.2-0ubuntu1), python3-ibus-1.0:amd64 (1.5.22-2ubuntu2, 1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1), netplan.io:amd64 (0.99-0ubuntu3~20.04.1, 0.99-0ubuntu3~20.04.2), gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:amd64 (20.04.0-1, 20.04.0-3~ubuntu20.04.1), libgphoto2-port12:amd64 (2.5.24-1, 2.5.25-0ubuntu0.1), uno-libs-private:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), language-pack-gnome-en:amd64 (1:20.04+20200416, 1:20.04+20200709), libvte-2.91-0:amd64 (0.60.1-1ubuntu1, 0.60.3-0ubuntu1~20.04), libedataserverui-1.2-2:amd64 (3.36.3-0ubuntu1.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu1), update-manager-core:amd64 (1:20.04.10, 1:20.04.10.1), gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 (3.24.18-1ubuntu1, 3.24.20-0ubuntu1), gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 (3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), libridl-java:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), xserver-common:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.1, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2), libevdocument3-4:amd64 (3.36.0-2, 3.36.7-0ubuntu1), alsa-ucm-conf:amd64 (1.2.2-1, 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.2), libuno-salhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.2, 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.3), libegl1:amd64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.1, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2), libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 (1.64.0-2, 1.64.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1), libgphoto2-6:amd64 (2.5.24-1, 2.5.25-0ubuntu0.1), libproxy1v5:amd64 (0.4.15-10, 0.4.15-10ubuntu1), gnome-user-docs:amd64 (3.36.1-0ubuntu1, 3.36.2+git20200704-0ubuntu0.1), libegl-mesa0:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), libreoffice-gtk3:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libfprint-2-2:amd64 (1:1.90.1+tod1-0ubuntu4, 1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), libsystemd0:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.1, 245.4-4ubuntu3.2), shotwell-common:amd64 (0.30.8-0ubuntu2, 0.30.10-0ubuntu0.1), libpulsedsp:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.2, 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.6), libgtk-3-common:amd64 (3.24.18-1ubuntu1, 3.24.20-0ubuntu1), libjuh-java:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgtk-3-0:amd64 (3.24.18-1ubuntu1, 3.24.20-0ubuntu1), libgl1:amd64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgjs0g:amd64 (1.64.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 1.64.3-1~ubuntu20.04.1), pulseaudio:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.2, 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.6), libreoffice-core:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libedata-cal-2.0-1:amd64 (3.36.3-0ubuntu1.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu1), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu2, 3.36.3.1-0ubuntu1), libasound2-data:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2), libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:amd64 (0.4.15-10, 0.4.15-10ubuntu1), update-manager:amd64 (1:20.04.10, 1:20.04.10.1), librsvg2-common:amd64 (2.48.2-1, 2.48.7-1ubuntu0.20.04.1), eog:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), sudo:amd64 (1.8.31-1ubuntu1, 1.8.31-1ubuntu1.1), gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0:amd64 (0.6.55-0ubuntu11, 0.6.55-0ubuntu12~20.04.1), python-apt-common:amd64 (2.0.0, 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.1), xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.1, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2), libgphoto2-l10n:amd64 (2.5.24-1, 2.5.25-0ubuntu0.1), gjs:amd64 (1.64.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 1.64.3-1~ubuntu20.04.1), libxatracker2:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), udev:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.1, 245.4-4ubuntu3.2), evolution-data-server:amd64 (3.36.3-0ubuntu1.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu1), passwd:amd64 (1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5, 1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04), libgles2:amd64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1), language-pack-en:amd64 (1:20.04+20200416, 1:20.04+20200709), orca:amd64 (3.36.1-0ubuntu1, 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), gir1.2-freedesktop:amd64 (1.64.0-2, 1.64.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1), nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal:amd64 (3.36.1.1-1ubuntu1, 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04), libmutter-6-0:amd64 (3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), initramfs-tools-bin:amd64 (0.136ubuntu6, 0.136ubuntu6.2), python3-uno:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libatk-adaptor:amd64 (2.34.1-3, 2.34.2-0ubuntu2~20.04.1), libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libudev1:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.1, 245.4-4ubuntu3.2), rsyslog:amd64 (8.2001.0-1ubuntu1, 8.2001.0-1ubuntu1.1), ibus-gtk:amd64 (1.5.22-2ubuntu2, 1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1), libgbm1:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), libfprint-2-tod1:amd64 (1:1.90.1+tod1-0ubuntu4, 1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), ibus-gtk3:amd64 (1.5.22-2ubuntu2, 1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1), mutter-common:amd64 (3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), systemd-timesyncd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.1, 245.4-4ubuntu3.2), gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu2, 3.36.3.1-0ubuntu1), deja-dup:amd64 (40.6-1ubuntu2, 40.7-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-base-core:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), xserver-xephyr:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.1, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2), apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.6, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8), libreoffice-ogltrans:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 (3.36.3-0ubuntu1.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu1), libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-impress:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), evince-common:amd64 (3.36.0-2, 3.36.7-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-style-elementary:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nautilus:amd64 (1:3.36.1.1-1ubuntu2, 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1), libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 (1:3.36.1.1-1ubuntu2, 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-docs:amd64 (20.04.2, 20.04.3), libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu2, 3.36.3.1-0ubuntu1), adwaita-icon-theme:amd64 (3.36.0-1ubuntu1, 3.36.1-2ubuntu0.20.04.2), busybox-static:amd64 (1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6, 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.1), libgtk-3-bin:amd64 (3.24.18-1ubuntu1, 3.24.20-0ubuntu1), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:20.04.18, 1:20.04.24), libebook-1.2-20:amd64 (3.36.3-0ubuntu1.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu1), libpulse0:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.2, 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.6), gir1.2-glib-2.0:amd64 (1.64.0-2, 1.64.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1), gir1.2-vte-2.91:amd64 (0.60.1-1ubuntu1, 0.60.3-0ubuntu1~20.04), python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:20.04.10, 1:20.04.10.1), libevview3-3:amd64 (3.36.0-2, 3.36.7-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:20.04.18, 1:20.04.24), librsvg2-2:amd64 (2.48.2-1, 2.48.7-1ubuntu0.20.04.1), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.6, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8), im-config:amd64 (0.44-1ubuntu1, 0.44-1ubuntu1.1), libjurt-java:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-help-common:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libfwupdplugin1:amd64 (1.3.9-4ubuntu0.1, 1.3.11-1~focal1), libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.2, 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.6), language-pack-gnome-en-base:amd64 (1:20.04+20200416, 1:20.04+20200709), systemd-sysv:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.1, 245.4-4ubuntu3.2), libldap-common:amd64 (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.2, 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.3), libreoffice-style-colibre:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglib2.0-bin:amd64 (2.64.2-1~fakesync1, 2.64.3-1~ubuntu20.04.1), ure:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-writer:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.1, 245.4-4ubuntu3.2), xwayland:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.1, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2), libreoffice-common:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), xz-utils:amd64 (5.2.4-1, 5.2.4-1ubuntu1), libglx0:amd64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1), systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.1, 245.4-4ubuntu3.2), libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager:amd64 (0.4.15-10, 0.4.15-10ubuntu1), wpasupplicant:amd64 (2:2.9-1ubuntu4, 2:2.9-1ubuntu4.1), shotwell:amd64 (0.30.8-0ubuntu2, 0.30.10-0ubuntu0.1), login:amd64 (1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5, 1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), openssh-client:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4, 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.1), libfwupd2:amd64 (1.3.9-4ubuntu0.1, 1.3.11-1~focal1), libnss-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.1, 245.4-4ubuntu3.2), fwupd-signed:amd64 (1.27.1ubuntu1+1.3.9-4ubuntu0.1, 1.27.1ubuntu2+1.3.11-1~focal1), libasound2:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2), libnetplan0:amd64 (0.99-0ubuntu3~20.04.1, 0.99-0ubuntu3~20.04.2), libglib2.0-data:amd64 (2.64.2-1~fakesync1, 2.64.3-1~ubuntu20.04.1), language-pack-en-base:amd64 (1:20.04+20200416, 1:20.04+20200709), bash:amd64 (5.0-6ubuntu1, 5.0-6ubuntu1.1), libuno-cppu3:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), ibus:amd64 (1.5.22-2ubuntu2, 1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1), libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64 (2.34.1-3, 2.34.2-0ubuntu2~20.04.1), thermald:amd64 (1.9.1-1ubuntu0.1, 1.9.1-1ubuntu0.2), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.6, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:20.04.18, 1:20.04.24), libvte-2.91-common:amd64 (0.60.1-1ubuntu1, 0.60.3-0ubuntu1~20.04), fonts-opensymbol:amd64 (2:102.11+LibO6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 2:102.11+LibO6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), fwupd:amd64 (1.3.9-4ubuntu0.1, 1.3.11-1~focal1), libebook-contacts-1.2-3:amd64 (3.36.3-0ubuntu1.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu1), gnome-terminal-data:amd64 (3.36.1.1-1ubuntu1, 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04), libgnutls30:amd64 (3.6.13-2ubuntu1.1, 3.6.13-2ubuntu1.2), unattended-upgrades:amd64 (2.3, 2.3ubuntu0.1), libibus-1.0-5:amd64 (1.5.22-2ubuntu2, 1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1), pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.2, 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.6), libedata-book-1.2-26:amd64 (3.36.3-0ubuntu1.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu1), gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 (1.5.22-2ubuntu2, 1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1), libreoffice-pdfimport:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libecal-2.0-1:amd64 (3.36.3-0ubuntu1.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu1), nautilus-data:amd64 (1:3.36.1.1-1ubuntu2, 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-style-tango:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), gtk-update-icon-cache:amd64 (3.24.18-1ubuntu1, 3.24.20-0ubuntu1), libuno-sal3:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), linux-firmware:amd64 (1.187, 1.187.3), mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), accountsservice:amd64 (0.6.55-0ubuntu11, 0.6.55-0ubuntu12~20.04.1), libreoffice-help-en-us:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-gnome:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libcamel-1.2-62:amd64 (3.36.3-0ubuntu1.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu1), libunoloader-java:amd64 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), liblzma5:amd64 (5.2.4-1, 5.2.4-1ubuntu1), libreoffice-calc:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), gnome-terminal:amd64 (3.36.1.1-1ubuntu1, 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04), pulseaudio-utils:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.2, 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.6), ibus-data:amd64 (1.5.22-2ubuntu2, 1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1), desktop-file-utils:amd64 (0.24-1ubuntu2, 0.24-1ubuntu3), gir1.2-rsvg-2.0:amd64 (2.48.2-1, 2.48.7-1ubuntu0.20.04.1), python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.6, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8), libedataserver-1.2-24:amd64 (3.36.3-0ubuntu1.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu1), libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.64.2-1~fakesync1, 2.64.3-1~ubuntu20.04.1), initramfs-tools-core:amd64 (0.136ubuntu6, 0.136ubuntu6.2), gnome-getting-started-docs:amd64 (3.36.1-0ubuntu1, 3.36.2-0ubuntu0.1), initramfs-tools:amd64 (0.136ubuntu6, 0.136ubuntu6.2), less:amd64 (551-1, 551-1ubuntu0.1), libatopology2:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2), libreoffice-draw:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), python3-apt:amd64 (2.0.0, 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libaccountsservice0:amd64 (0.6.55-0ubuntu11, 0.6.55-0ubuntu12~20.04.1), mutter:amd64 (3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), base-files:amd64 (11ubuntu5, 11ubuntu5.1), gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 (67ubuntu20.04.5, 68ubuntu1~20.04.1), libglx-mesa0:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), libglvnd0:amd64 (1.3.1-1, 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1), busybox-initramfs:amd64 (1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6, 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.1)
End-Date: 2020-08-31  17:59:25

Start-Date: 2020-08-31  18:59:39
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.140'
Install: linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-45.49, automatic), linux-headers-5.4.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-45.49, automatic), linux-modules-5.4.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-45.49, automatic), linux-headers-5.4.0-45:amd64 (5.4.0-45.49, automatic), linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-45.49, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0.42.46, 5.4.0.45.49), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-42.46, 5.4.0-45.49), yaru-theme-icon:amd64 (20.04.7, 20.04.8), simple-scan:amd64 (3.36.0-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.0), yaru-theme-gtk:amd64 (20.04.7, 20.04.8), libisc-export1105:amd64 (1:9.11.16+dfsg-3~build1, 1:9.11.16+dfsg-3~ubuntu1), linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0.42.46, 5.4.0.45.49), linux-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0.42.46, 5.4.0.45.49), yaru-theme-gnome-shell:amd64 (20.04.7, 20.04.8), libdns-export1109:amd64 (1:9.11.16+dfsg-3~build1, 1:9.11.16+dfsg-3~ubuntu1), yaru-theme-sound:amd64 (20.04.7, 20.04.8)
End-Date: 2020-08-31  19:01:14
```

Comment: There is no `history` entry in my `/var/log`. Is there an alternative way to do that?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question.

Comment: Your output shows no deb package removals during the week you posted. How did you install Java originally? Did you install Java using a deb...or some other way?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember. I usually use apt, so I would assume that was it unless it already came with Ubuntu.

Comment: Let's try `dpkg -l | grep jre`. That will show all the JRE packages that the system knows about. Rows beginning with `ii` are installed.

Comment: It only shows the JDK I installed today after I realized I was missing Java. I edited the question to include that information.

Comment: Could it be that PyCharm has its own included JRE and that somehow broke?

Comment: I re-installed PyCharm today with snap and indeed it is running with an included Java: `/snap/pycharm-community/209/jbr/bin/java`. I deleted the previous PyCharm but I would guess it was doing the same. Not sure why it stopped working all of a sudden, though.

Comment: One hypothesis is that I needed to run the PyCharm shell script launcher from a specific directory and was not doing that, in which case it looked for JAVA_HOME and did not find it since I didn't have a JRE installed.